# Change typeface in a field in beamer

Tags: beamer, typefaces

In beamer, to set e.g. title in bold I can use `\textbf` as in

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{\textbf{Title}}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

How would a skilled beamer expert approach this problem?

Comment: May I suggest the  section `3 Tutorial: Euclid’s Presentation` from the beamer user guide? In a few pages it gives an overview how to change such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamerfont{title}{series=\bfseries}

\title{Title}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```